# Consulta SQL con subquery funciona en SQL SERVER 2016, pero no funciona en SQL CE

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

Mi consulta SQL con subquery funciona en SQL SERVER 2016, pero no funciona en SQL CE. Quisiera transformar a LINQ. Gracias y Saludos

```
select 
  f.CSucursal, 
  f.NSucursal, 
  f.Correlativo, 
  sum(f.EPedido) as EPedido, 
  c.CCanal from `(` 
select 
  CSucursal, 
  NSucursal, 
  case when SBulto = 1 then s.Correlativo else o.Correlativo end as Correlativocase when SBulto = 1 then s.Unidad else EPedido end as EPedido 
from 
  Jumbo.Oc as o 
  LEFT JOIN Jumbo.SBulto AS s ON o.Id = s.Oc_Id 
where 
  o.Rut = 89650200 
  AND o.Orden = 5573308215 
  AND o.Carga = 1 
  AND o.CPallet = 0 `) as f` 
  left join Jumbo.Canal as c on c.CSucursal = f.CSucursal 
group by 
  f.CSucursal, 
  f.NSucursal, 
  f.Correlativo, 
  c.CCanal
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Debo estandarizar mi CONSULTA SQL para trabajar tanto SQL SERVER como SQL COMPACT por eso quiero transformar a LINQ

Comment: Qué error obtienes? Qué probaste para transformarla? En su formato actual, estás pidiendo que alguien tome la consulta y haga algo, sin más

Comment: Alfabravo, este es mi error, System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: 'El nombre de tabla no es válido. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 267,Table name = Oc ]'

Comment: Sorry estoy debutando.

Comment: `El nombre de tabla no es válido`,  ¿has verificado que la tabla `Oc` exista? ¿Que tenga el mismo owner?

Comment: Entity se encarga de mis tablas, funciona excelente. Encontré esto en la comunidad y creo es el problema ("La limitación en SQL CE es que no admite subconsultas")

Comment: No tengo experiencia con CE, lo que dices sin duda es un problema, por que tu query tiene una subconsulta, sin embargo lo raro, es que el error lo pareciera dar con la tabla que ya está adentro de la subconsulta

Answer (score 0):

Consulta SQL con SUBQUERY a LINQ funcionando con SQL SERVER y COMPACT. El método `DefaultIfEmpty()` permitío crear los LEFT JOIN. Comparto para sugerencias o recomendaciones.

```
var query = from oc in db.Ocs
    join sb in db.SBultos on oc.Id equals sb.Oc_Id into ocsb
    from ocsb0 in ocsb.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where oc.Rut == ValorRut && oc.Orden == ValorOrden && oc.Carga == ValorCarga && oc.CPallet == 0
    join ca in db.Canales on oc.CSucursal equals ca.CSucursal into ocsb0ca
    from ocsb0ca0 in ocsb0ca.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { CSucursal = oc.CSucursal, Correlativo = oc.SBulto ? ocsb0.Correlativo : oc.Correlativo, EPedido = oc.SBulto ? ocsb0.Unidad : oc.EPedido, CCanal = ocsb0ca0.CCanal } into FinQuery
    group FinQuery by new { FinQuery.CSucursal, FinQuery.Correlativo, FinQuery.CCanal, FinQuery.EPedido } into FinGroup
    select new { Csucursal = FinGroup.Key.CSucursal, Correlativo = FinGroup.Key.Correlativo, EPedido = FinGroup.Sum(x=>x.EPedido), CCanal = FinGroup.Key.CCanal }
```